# Data loss in Java Swing Socket

Tags: java, swing, sockets

Im working on a chat project using java swing where i am using Socket programming for chat msg, commands etc. While testing i found that there is data loss in transfers send to server program from client program through socket. After a deep study of code i found that each msg or command send through client program is received with an interval of 650 milliseconds. In between if i try to send more than 1 command like "cmd 1", "cmd 2" and "cmd 3", i receive only "cmd 1" and the second msg gets disappeared or not received and after few milliseconds "cmd 3" receives. Please suggest me a socket program where no data loss should occur to make the program look live.

Comment: Without any code it is difficult to diagnose the error.

Comment: What's a Swing socket? Never heard nor seen something a like?

Comment: @Guillaume Polet: A swing socket, otherwise known as a swing hanger, is the children's swing set part where you hook a swing, so the swing can swing back and forth.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I am confused because he tagged his question with "Swing" tag which refers to Java Swing Toolkit.

Comment: @Guillaume Polet: The OP used Java Swing to build the GUI and Java socket programming to have the client and server communicate.  The question has nothing to do with Swing.  My previous comment was a joke.

Answer (score 1):

> Please suggest me a socket program where no data loss should occur to make the program look live.

Sure.  Your server or client should send a command and wait for a response before sending another command.  That's how the Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) works.

Here are some [Java socket programming examples](http://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/javanetexamples/) that use a command / response protocol.  The last example is a chat client and server.